# Countable union of intervals

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} (-\infty,a-1/n)=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} (-\infty,a-1/n]$?

It seems that both equal $(-\infty,a)$.

Comment: Yes, both equal $(-\infty,a)$.

Comment: Yep.  They are the same.  FWIW Note:  Then only difference between $(-\infty,a-\frac 1n)$ and $(-\infty, a-\frac 1n]$ is that the second one contains the point $a-\frac 1n$ and the first one doesn't.  But as that point, $a-\frac 1n$ will be contained in the next inteval in the union, $(-\infty, a-\frac 1{n+1})$ it's in the union anyway.  It just comes from a different place.  (In local fashion this is just like $(2, 4) \cup (3,5) = (2,5)$ while $(2,4]\cup [3,5) = (2,5)$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convince yourself this is true, let $x$ be any element less than $a$; i.e., let $x$ belong to the set $(-\infty, a)$. Do you agree that there must be an $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x \leq a - 1/n$?

If you do, then this would mean that $x\in (a, a - 1/n]$ for that $n$. Thus, by the arbitrary-ness of $x$, this means that $(-\infty, a)\subseteq \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (-\infty, a - 1/n]$ (and also that $(-\infty, a)\subseteq \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (-\infty, a - 1/n)$).